# How to catch system web search in a browser app?

Tags: android, search, intentfilter

I'm building a browser app in android and I want to allow the user to be able to open web searches from around the system in my browser.

For example web searches from selections:

[image: web searches]

And if possible searches from the home screen search widget.

Currently both open in the google app despite me registering an intent filter for WEB_SEARCH.

Here is my activity definition in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".Browser"
    android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:resizeableActivity="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_BROWSER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <!-- Allows activity to be opened for links around the OS -->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <!-- *should* catches system google searches? wasn't able to trigger it -->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.WEB_SEARCH" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I was expecting next time I hit web search for android to ask me which app I wished to use but so far nothing, it automatically goes to google app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.WEB_SEARCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```